# iOS: React native version 0..72.1 -> 'react/debug/react_native_assert.h' file not found error

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, cross-platform, podfile

I get the error: 'react/debug/react_native_assert.h' file not found, React-utils/RunLoopObserver. The problem seems to be a pre_install hook that i added:

```
dynamic_frameworks = [
    'Starscream',
    'iProov',
    'DatadogSDK',
    'SwiftProtobuf',
]
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if !dynamic_frameworks.include?(pod.name)
      puts "Overriding the static_framework? method for #{pod.name}"
      def pod.static_framework?;
        true
      end
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.static_library
      end
    end
  end
end

I cannot remove the pre_install hook as it is required to run one of my dependencies
```

Comment: Many people seem to have this issue. You can follow the update on github here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38283
(still no solution)

Comment: I though that `["React-cxxreact", "React-NativeModulesApple", "RNGestureHandler", ...` in Podfile would fix the issue but that runs into other issues. Any idea if a update to 0.73 fixes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

use this command
USE_FRAMEWORKS=static NO_FLIPPER=1 pod install

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38140

its working in my case.